# How to rewrite Rails assets path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I began moving all the assets in my site to S3 and ran into a problem with my asset path.
There's a WYSIWYG editor on my site that includes images by absolute path, so when you add an image, it doesn't use the rails image_tag helper but rather adds an image like this:

```
<img src="/system/images/image_1.jpg" />
```

The problem is that in production the URL `/system/images/image_1.jpg` leads to a non-existant file.

Naturally, two solutions are to 1) replace the URL dynamically (gsub) when it's called and 2) to loop through the database and replace the urls.

A better solution, however, would be to rewrite the `/system/images/image_1.jpg` url to point to S3. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any chance you can update the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: I can for the future, but right now I have easily about 10000 records already written like this